# How can I bind:style with object syntax and multiple background images?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to bind css style with the [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) to an image.
the style object contains the css property `background` refering to multiple background images. Unfortunately, these images are not displayed.

*Template*

```
<v-img
    :src="require('../assets/background/bg_0.png')"
    :style="bg"
></v-img>
```

*Script*

```
data() {
    return {
        bg: {
            background: "url('~@/assets/pieces/animals/animal_1.png') no-repeat center, url('~@/assets/pieces/animals/animal_3.png') no-repeat center",
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px"
    }
}
}
```

The properties for `width` and `height` are working, but the two images from `background` are not displayed.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The background CSS is technically correct, but I believe your issue is the image path. That path prefix `~@` won't work here because you haven't required the image so Webkit doesn't know about it. My recommendation would be to require the image first and then pass it as a constant to the `bg` object. That would clean things up by splitting code up over multiple lines and still allow you to use your path prefix for the dynamic URLs.

Something like this

```
const animal1 = require('~@/assets/pieces/animals/animal_1.png')
const animal3 = require('~@/assets/pieces/animals/animal_3.png')
data() {
    return {
        bg: {
            background: `url(${animal1}) no-repeat center, url(${animal3}) no-repeat center`,
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px"
        }
    }
}
```